# How to guess the Chemical state in which particular element will be present from XPS data?

Tags: spectroscopy

Since my last post yesterday, I found some leads and started to analyse my data. But then I started encountering more doubts, questions and confusion. Any help will be highly appreciated and will help me in speeding my research.

For analysis, I am matching the peak binding energy for each orbital for each element with the NIST Reference Database. During the analysis process I was confused how to guess in what form is the element/element's present. I am not sure what I am doing is correct or not.

I am analysing XPS results of Pt impregnated on gamma alumina. I have 4 samples each subjected to different conditions. I am trying to figure out in what oxidation state/in what form the Pt will be present.

So I'll give an example -

For Pt, I got a peak binding energy of 74.76 eV for the 4f7/2 orbital. When I searched this peak in the reference database, I got the following possible candidates with the following reference binding energies

a) PtO - 74.6 eV

b) PtO2 - 74.6 eV

c) Pt - 74.5 eV

This particular sample was fired in an engine and the temperatures were around 300 deg cel, and we don't know exactly in what form the Pt will be present. How do I decipher in what state the Pt will present from the XPS data ?

Comment: Where do you get these data? I get from https://www.jp.xpssimplified.com/elements/platinum.php: 71.0, 72.4, 74.9 for the same compounds in the given order, in which case your compound is more definitely PtO2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, there a lot of XPS questions here which are being closed or not receiving an answer. The problem is that you are not sharing enough experimental details so nobody has an answer and nobody knows if your 74.76 eV peak is at the true position or not (see the reasons below). You also need get a good XPS textbook written by the very inventor of XPS. Check Wikipedia about the inventor of XPS.

When people wish to assign XPS to a certain oxidation state or assign a certain compound, here are some of the steps that help people in interpretation.

1. One should be aware of the fact that there are two types of X-ray photoelectron spectra. Survey scans which are acquired rapidly, or high resolution scans which take several hours or even a full day. *Peak assignments should be done on high resolution scans*. A survey scan is a quick and dirty analysis and this is most likely done in your case. High resolution scans are expensive.
2. Peak positions are very sensitive to charged state of the surface. By chance, if you have seen scanning electron microscopy of particles, one can see particles flying from the surface due to charging. Similar charging effects exist in XPS. If the XPS substrate to be analyzed is being electrically charged by impinging X-rays, the peak positions will be shifted.
3. Usually adventitious carbon (always present on all samples) is used to correct the peak positions. Peak assignments should not be done on uncorrected spectra.

*Now the **74.76 eV** value can be a useful number OR it can be completely useless if steps or conditions (1) to (3) were not fulfilled.*

4. The fourth step is to use chemical intuition about the nature of the surface. Do you expect such compounds on the surface? Was Pt present in an oxidative environment? If you think there is negatively charged platinum species, the charge must be balanced by some cations. Is there an indication of cations present on the surface. If you assign PtO formation, is there a oxygen peak in similar proportion to Pt atom %?
5. Look at peak widths of the element in question. A wide peak indicates multiple environments or oxidation states. This is done by peak fitting (wrongly called deconvolution in common parlance) in the software. CASA XPS manuals are online.
6. In short do not look at just at a single number from the NIST table, look at the conditions in which that NIST data was acquired and also see how good quality XPS data is summarized. They write all the details. Ask your XPS data provider to show all the conditions too (peak position correction, baseline correction method etc).
   **Your 74.76 eV can only be assigned to a certain oxidation or compound if and only if your AND their experimental conditions match closely.** Otherwise, everything will be handwaving. A lot of XPS data in analytical literature is based on handwaving because XPS peak assignment is not a trivial task. This is from the NIST website. Note they do not mention uncertainity, which is also important.

[XPS for Pt](https://srdata.nist.gov/xps/XPSDetailPage.aspx?AllDataNo=41551#Data_process.htm)

.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this detailed answer. This certainly helped me a lot and cleared a lot of my doubts. I also went through a basic XPS textbook, which also helped in grasping the basic textbooks. Is it okay if I dm you? ,I had a few more detailed doubts after following your answer

Comment: Wulf, I am not an expert in XPS at all. I was just a user for my research work. You can try posting crystal clear questions so that everyone can benefit from the discussion. I don't know how dm works.